# Has anyone else experienced a crash with boost::exception_ptr as a member of an object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, exception, crash

The following code works fine:

```
{
    boost::exception_ptr error;
}
```

The following code crashes:

```
struct Obj
{
    boost::exception_ptr error;
};

{
    Obj obj;
}
```

The error indicated is:
    Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

My question is what's the difference between destroying an object using function scope, and destroying an object using object scope?

Comment: Works fine with VS2010. Might help if you tell us boost version, OS, compiler version etc. Also why is this question tagged "multi-threaded"?

Comment: Jon, the tag is a result of me not considering how much of my project I was going to expose in my question. Also, since posting this, I've discovered that renaming the object causes the problematic behavior to go away. I'm trusting that a clean rebuild of my projects from the ground up will solve this problem. None of it makes sense, and it's not really worthy of a public viewing - it's just Visual Studio (2008) in a bad state I think.